# Cannot read property 'status' of undefined - Error before function actually works?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I am working with a  dropdown, and the [selected] tag for Angular appears to be throwing me a few problems...

It appears that, although my code brings back everything I am expecting, matching the dropdown value displayed to the current state of my event, it is throwing an error stating:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'status' of undefined

Perhaps it is attempting to assign a value to [selected] before it has had chance to actually look? Jumping the gun a little?

**html**

```
<select>
   <option *ngFor="let x of options" [selected]="isCurrent(x.name)">{{x.name}}</option>
</select>
```

**component**

```
isCurrent(status: string): boolean {
    return this.event.status == status;
  }
```

this.event is an object with makeup:

```
export interface IEvent extends IEntity {
  date: Date;  //  YYYY-MM-DD'T'HH:MM:ss.SSSZ
  status: string;
  stage: IEntity;
  entrants?: IEntrant[];
}
```

Comment: Seems that it start comparing status with event.status before event gets any value.

Comment: Where do you first set a value for `this.event`? If it's *after* `options` has a `length` > 0 then this error makes perfect sense.

Comment: Not related, but you shouldn't call methods in template. They are run on each change detection, which is quite often. In worst case you can end up in what seems to be an infinite loop. So use variables in templates instead :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid calling methods in template, because they are called on each change detection. Use variables instead. The error you are getting is that it seems that `event` is `undefined`, therefore it cannot read `status`. You can solve that by initializing it in your component:

```
event = <IEvent>{};
```

Also like I suggested, use variable instead. You can use this:

```
<select>
  <option *ngFor="let x of options" [selected]="x.name === event.status">
    {{x.name}} 
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: I actually went for something similar, going with `*ngIf="event?.status"` in the containing html component

Comment: Sure you can do that too! I myself find it as a good practice to initialize variables to avoid unnecessary `*ngIf`'s if you can. It's a matter of opinion I guess, and also if you want to actually hide content before the data has been populated :)

Answer (score 3):

Try extend your `isCurrent` function like this:

```
isCurrent(status: string): boolean {
    // firstly check that event exists
    return this.event && this.event.status == status;
}
```

Seems that `event` is undefined or null in the beginning and gets value asynchronously, later than first checks run.

Comment: Aha! You have given me the inspiration @Artem. I have sorted it with doing `if (this.event) { return this.event.status === status } return false;`

Comment: @physicsboy actually i did the same in this code, but with shorter expression.

Comment: I have since changed it to use `*ngIf="event?.status"` in the containing html component